# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found

Tags: java, ssl

In my web application, when it tries to fire an HTTP request to itself I get this exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.smcc.od.common.capi.OdCommonHelper.processHttpURLConnection(OdCommonHelper.java:593)
    at com.smcc.od.common.pipelet.http.ProcessHttpURLConnection.execute(ProcessHttpURLConnection.java:113)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:346)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1116)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:944)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
    at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.pipelet.pipeline.ExecutePipeline$PipelineExecutor.run(ExecutePipeline.java:440)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.execute.ExecutorServiceImpl$ClosingCurrentResourcesRunnable.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:231)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:462)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

The URL which is called is something like `https://localhost:448/foo/bar`.

Searching for a solution, I've tried to create a self-signed HTTPS certificate and to import it in my JRE's keystore.

I have run this command through Powershell to create a self-signed certificate for `localhost`:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "localhost" -FriendlyName "localhost" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Then I copied that certificate in under Trusted Root Certification Authorities. I've exported it in a .cer through MMC file and I have imported it in my JRE through the command

```
& 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe' -importcert -file D:\temp\certificate\localhost.cer -keystore 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\jre\lib\security\cacerts' -alias "localhost"
```

which returned

```
Certificate was added to keystore
```

I have restarted my application server and I tried to perform that self-HTTP request again, but I still got the SSLException.

I have checked if the certificate has been really imported in the JRE, and it is:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe' -keystore 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.222.10-hotspot\jre\lib\security\cacerts' -list | Select-String "localhost"
```

which returned

```
localhost, Oct 28, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
```

I am unable to add a custom `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` implementation to skip `localhost` validation. Is there some configuration I am missing?

My local environment is on Windows 10. My web server is Apache.

Comment: Just adding a random certificate to the trust store won't help. It has to be the same certificate that apache is using. And unless this is just for development, it's not going to work. A web server shouldn't be sending requests to itself in the first place.